# Adding a Tab Bar to NavigationController using interface builder, not intuitive at all

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar

I have this ViewController as the root view controller. This VC is embed in a navigation controller. So, the navigation controller is the initial controller.

I have worked millions of times with an app like this.

If I want to add buttons to my nav bar I go to the navigation controller, turn on TOP BAR property to translucent navigation bar and now I can add buttons to the nav bar on my view controller.

But this app is different. I need a tab bar at the bottom too. So, I follow the same logic. I go to the navigation bar, turn on BOTTOM BAR property to Translucent Black Tab Bar, a black rectangle appears at the bottom of my view controller and BOOM, I cannot add buttons to it. Same logic, different behaviors.

If I try to add a tab bar to the black rectangle Xcode will not accept.

I want to add this tab bar to the bottom of the view controller and make it translucent, so the collectionView this controller has will be partially visible thru it.

So the question is: what is the purpose of the BOTTOM BAR property of the navigation controller if it will not accept dragging tab bar items to it? How do I add a tab bar to my navigation controller or to its root view controller using this stuff? Or in other words: how do I add a tab bar to the bottom of a view controller that has a collection view covering the whole are and make that tab bar translucent, so I can see the contents of the collection view passing thru...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottom bar of a `UINnavigationController` is a UIToolbar and if shown the navigation controller should automatically adjust the insets of the collectionView (and other scrollView) to make the content appear under them when you scroll.

I've encountered the problem of adding elements to that bar myself and the only way that I've found is to do that in code accessing the `toolbar` property of your navigation controller and set the `items` property with your `UIBarButtoItem`s. As you want to make a segmented controller-like component I suggest an item with a custom view.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer the first question, but as for the second- drag a `Tab Bar Controller` onto the canvass the same way you would with a new View Controller. Make this new `Tab Bar Controller` the initial View Controller. CTRL-drag from the Tab Bar Controller to any of the view controllers (or navigation controllers) for which you want a tab bar button. Select "View Controller" as the segue type. The tab bar button for that segue will appear at the bottom of both the Tab Bar Controller and the View Controller itself, and you can change the text or image by clicking it and opening the Identity Inspector.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't want to deal with a tab bar controller because I don't want to deal with two view controllers. My tab bar is to work like a segmented controller but a prettier one. Segmented control is ugly. I want to use a tab bar, just that.